# SSRS report viewer in MVC Error (ReportViewerForMVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, reportingservices-2005, reportviewerformvc

I am trying to include SSRS (.rdl) in my MVC application. It always give me error:

```
The WebResource.axd handler must be registered in the configuration to process this request.

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <httpHandlers>
           <add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True" />
       </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have installed

```
Microsoft.Report.Viewer v. 11.0.0
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms 14.1000.523
ReportViewerForMVC
```

Here is my code:

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
                reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
                reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + @"Areas\Daleel.HRIS\Reports\DailyAttendance.rdl";
                reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", data));

                ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
```

View:

```
@using ReportViewerForMvc;
<div class="ui attached very relaxed segment">
    <div class="ui container">

        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)

    </div>
</div>
```

WEbconfig:

```
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="false" />

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" waitChangeNotification="0" maxWaitChangeNotification="0" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <compilation>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
<handlers>
      <clear />
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />    
  </system.webServer>
```

Can anyone help me fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done what the error message is asking you?
Adding the handler in the web.config

Comment: Looks like it's in the wrong section though,<system.web><httpHandlers> not in <system.webServer><handlers>

Comment: it is in both places

Comment: Can any one suggest for this error , I am also facing this issue @Html.ReportViewer  not found.